# How to set multiple canvas background to multiply individual color?

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to use multiple canvases and set different background for each canvas. I assign canvas's background to a random color generation function. But it returns only one color for all canvas.

wpf example:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Canvas Name="canvas1" Grid.Column="0"></Canvas>
    <Canvas Name="canvas2" Grid.Column="1"></Canvas>
</Grid>
```

c# example:

```
    private void SetColor()
    {
         canvas1.Background = new SolidColorBrush(RandomNewColor());
         canvas2.Background = new SolidColorBrush(RandomNewColor());
    }

    private Color RandomNewColor()
    {
        Random RandomColor = new Random();
        Byte[] _byte = new Byte[3];

        RandomColor.NextBytes(_byte);
        byte red = _byte[0];
        byte green = _byte[1];
        byte blue = _byte[2];

        return Color.FromArgb(255, red, green, blue);
    }
```

Comment: Standard bug, you need to call the Random constructor only once.  Make it a field of your class instead of a local variable.

Answer (score 2):

The Random class uses a seed value to generate its sequence of numbers. By calling it without a parameter, it is using the system clock for the seed and most likely being called too quickly between the 2 canvas controls so ends up using the same seed value for both. From the [docs at Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> However, because the clock has finite resolution, using the
>   parameterless constructor to create different Random objects in close
>   succession creates random number generators that produce identical
>   sequences of random numbers.

You could add a parameter to the constructor call but I don't think that will really solve your problem. Best to move the instance of Random out and make it a single instance as a class member. i.e.

```
private Random RandomColor = new Random();
private Color RandomNewColor()
    {
        Byte[] _byte = new Byte[3];
        RandomColor.NextBytes(_byte);
```